# Countably additive map on an algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

When one talks about a countably additive map on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Where $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of a set $X$ such that $X \in \mathcal{A}$, $A \in \mathcal{A}$ iff $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$ and all finite unions of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are in $\mathcal{A}$.

How is this actually defined? As by definition of an algebra, it may be that not all countable unions of elements in $\mathcal{A}$ are in $\mathcal{A}$. So is it defined to be countably additive on $\mathcal{A}$ when the countable union lies in $\mathcal{A}$

I'm pretty sure this must be the case as otherwise the unions may 'spill out' to a larger subset of $P(X)$, and hence the map could no longer be a map from just $\mathcal{A}$. But I thought I'd check for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it defined to be countably additive on $\mathcal{A}$ when the countable union lies in $\mathcal{A}$

Exactly, this is the way to go. More precisely: Countable additivity here means $\mu \left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$ for all sequences of pairwise disjoint elements $(A_n)_n \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ such that $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal{A}$.